# Emacs auto-revert remote image file

Tags: auto-revert-mode, revert-buffer

I would like to auto-revert some remote image/pdf files.

I have activated the option 
`(setq auto-revert-remote-files t)` and see that the file effectively auto-revert. Yet the image does not update. I need to go to the image buffer and toggle between editing or viewing the `C-c C-c` to see the changes. 
Is there a way to avoid the last step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds similar to Emacs bug 21598, [see here](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21598). Could you pls check whether it is the same problem?

Comment: It is on my todo list to be solved. With lower priority, 'tho.

Comment: Ok. I will validate your answer and come back if I have any news.

Comment: I think if we can set (image-toggle-display)  each time after remote file is reverted it should work. but my knowledge is limited here.